# Preventing navigation to ChildWindow in Silverlight

Tags: c#, performance, security, silverlight

When we try **to navigate** to `ChildWIndow` using AddressString of the Browser the method

```
  private void ContentFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
```

does not executing.

And instead of the error happens here

```
private void ContentFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
            e.Handled = true;
            // ErrorWindow.CreateNew(e.Exception);
}
```

How to prevent to navigate to the `ChildWindow`?

Thank you!